# How to dictate single letters and number to Android?

Tags: voice-recognition, gboard

at the job we routinely use a web application through our smartphones and on one of its screens we have to input the chassis number of cars, technically called [V.I.N.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_identification_number). Just to let you know, a likely VIN could be something like "LJCP013X00123...4F"

We would like to dictate those VINs because we usually wear gloves while we use this web app.

Now... I tried to dictate single letters as "El", "Jay", "Cee", "Pee", "Zero", and so on.

But Android goes nuts, tries to come up with a word that obviously does not exist and just stop listening.

Do you know if there is a workaround to dictate single letters and digits to Android?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out this behaviour was partially dependant on our application. Our application used to mingle with the dictated text to convert in upper case and to remove blanks while dictating. Once this behaviour has been turned off, we are able to dictate letters and digits too.

Comment: And how exactly did you dictate?